# Where is the best place to find pre-made, open source, java packages?

Tags: java, open-source

I am looking for something like a portal, or a community where everybody posts their contributions in Java.

Ex. polynomial calculations, ...

Scenario:  Search -> "polynomial" -> download package (source code)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use [Google](http://google.com) for this. Just add the keyword "java" and maybe "open source" and/or "api". E.g.

- http://www.google.com/search?q=java+polynomial
- http://www.google.com/search?q=java+polynomial+open+source
- http://www.google.com/search?q=java+polynomial+api

Or if it is hard to find or you're looking for certain implementations, then try "guessing" the classname.

- http://www.google.com/search?q=%22public+class+polynomial%22

Another examples:

- http://www.google.com/search?q=%22extends+HttpServlet%22
- http://www.google.com/search?q=%22implements+ServletContextListener%22

Answer (score 0):

There is no such single place where you can search and download, try different sources like source forge, java-source.net, apache.. or simply the best "Google it"

Answer (score 0):

I frequently stumble upon [java-source.net](http://java-source.net/), but I don't think people start from a specific site: if you need a math library, you ask google for "math java open source" or something similar.